# How many primes of the form $2^p-p$ with $p$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that if $p = 6k+1$ with $k$ integer, then $(2^p-p) \mod 6 \equiv 1$. I think that this means that $2^p-p$ could be prime. My question is: are there a finite or infinite number of primes which can be written like this?

Comment: Note: All primes after 3 can be written in the form of $6k+1$ and $6k-1$

Comment: Also worth noting that non-prime may work: $2^9-9=503$ is prime

Comment: https://oeis.org/A048744 gives the first $23$ values of $n$ for which $2^n-n$ is prime, including the prime values $n=2,3,13,19$, and $481801$.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I do not have complete explanation of your question but with the use of my own properties of primes which I discovered last year I made a conclusion i.e.:

If (2<sup>p</sup> - 5) and (2<sup>p</sup> + 5) are primes than (2<sup>p</sup> - a) and (2<sup>p</sup> + a) are also primes only and only if "a" is a multiple of 5(which is rare but can come) or "a" is a prime number maybe "p" also.

**7 also show similar property in (2<sup>p</sup> - 7) and (2<sup>p</sup> + 7)**